# Bower Error: Failed UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE

Tags: jquery, node.js, bower

I received errors as in the following when I tried to install jquery using bower.

`bower install jquery --save`

`bower error         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/jquery failed: UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE`

Please help thanks.

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Might be the same problem that I had 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31699042/using-npm-behind-firewall-using-visual-studio-2015

Answer (score 13):

I had this problem because bower couldn't verify the ssl signature correctly (because of our network). I added this to the .bowerrc file, and its solved the problem:

```
{
  "strict-ssl": false
}
```

I found this solution [here](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/468)

Comment: I tried all sorts of proxy settings (since that's what gh threads suggested), but this answer was what I actually needed. Thanks!

Comment: This answer worked for me too. Should be accepted as a solution. Thanks @amichai!