# Using npm behind firewall using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-2015

I try to utilize the new npm support in Visual Studio 2015, but are hitting some problems. I'm located behind a corporate firewall.

I have tried to add "grunt" from the package.json file, and can see this output related to npm.

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-bower-task
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-cssmin
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-bower-task
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-cssmin
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-bower-task
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-cssmin
npm ERR! Error: UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1367:32)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.emit (events.js:92:17)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:979:10)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:471:13)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:340:10)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:368:25)
npm ERR!     at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:225:10)
npm ERR!     at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:215:5)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:182:11)
npm ERR!     at write (_stream_readable.js:601:24)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\Microsoft\\Web Tools\\External\\\\node\\node" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\Microsoft\\Web Tools\\External\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Data\Develop\Playground\WebBasics2
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm
```

I have seen some posts where you can configure node to ignore SSL, but don't know how to do this in Visual Studio 2015.

Please help
Best regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following steps will work for VS 2015

1- Run  command prompt as **Administrator**

2- go to *`Path of External tools`* for VS 2015 in your case it is  "
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Editors

3- npm config set ca=""

4- npm config set strict-ssl false

5- npm install npm -g --ca=null

For **Visual Studio 2017 Professional** Please check the comments by Jignesh Hirpara

Comment: As of update 3, the location of external tools is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External

Comment: For VS- 2017 use below Path
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Editors

Answer (score 5):

In my case the above solution did not work. It worked after updating .npmrc file and when running npm with a help of Fiddler. Here are the steps that worked for me:

- After installed npm, update .npmrc file located in C:\Users\'username' directory:

registry=http://registry.npmjs.org

proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8888

https-proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8888

http-proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8888

strict-ssl=false

- Open Fiddler, and under 'Rules' tab select 'Authomatically Authenticate'. Lets not forget Fiddler listens on port 8888
- While having Fiddler open, the npm command shouwl work just fine within Visual Studio

This should work behind corporate firewall, with domain joined systems.

Comment: This worked for me. I believe it's because I'm working behind a corporate proxy that uses [NTLM authentication](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2119)  that npm doesn't support. Thus the need to route through a local fiddler proxy that does support it - real pain.